# How to determine the subnet mask of a network using the minimum number of ICMP echo requests?

Tags: subnet, icmp

How to determine the subnet mask of a network using the minimum number of ICMP echo requests?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to generate a [ICMP Mask Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Address_Mask_Request), you should receive a [ICMP Mask Reply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Address_Mask_Reply).  It should take only 1 request.

Answer (score 0):

[ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) is used for error checking to see if a host exists...I am not 100% sure if you can do a lookup to check the subnet mask...unless you got the protocol usage mixed up.... I think it's the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) protocol that you are mixing up with...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to ruin, but you can not determine the subnet mask using ICMP...
I don't know if there is a real way to find out beside asking the LAN router (probably using SNMP)